# Angular 2 routerLink params & query params

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular5, angular4-router

Here is my route:

```
{ path: 'market/:currency', component: MainlayoutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
```

I want redirect to with query params like this:

**market/btc?sidebar=home**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/market', currency]" [queryParams]="{sidebar: 'home'}"></a>
```

But when i click its redirect **market/btc**

What's the problem.

Editing

This code works i have another bug but i solved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you just need to preserve your queryParams :

`queryParamsHandling="preserve"`

Add the above attribute/directive to your route :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/market', currency]" [queryParams]="{sidebar: 'home'}" queryParamsHandling="preserve"></a>
```

Comment: Out of topic, but where could I find documentation for that `queryParams` input ? I don't recall seeing it in the routing guide

Comment: @trichetriche it is a part of NavigationExtras : https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments

Comment: mention not @trichetriche :)

Answer (score 8):

you can try:

```
<a [routerLink]="'/market/'+ currency" [queryParams]="{sidebar: 'home'}"></a>
```

or:

```
<a routerLink = "/market/{{currency}}" [queryParams]="{sidebar: 'home'}"></a>
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no issue in your code. I tried following and its working nicely.

I have even added an extra parameter.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/market', currency]" [queryParams]="{sidebar:'home',tab:'5'}">Go to market</a>
```

TS :

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "market/:currency", component: AppComponent}
];
```

I am getting following result :

> http://localhost:49152/market/currency?sidebar=home&tab=5

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/market', currency]" [queryParams]="{sidebar: home}"></a>
```